# How can I get the look and feel of Sony's Android on my HTC

Tags: customization

The same Android version often looks different on phones from different manufacturers.
For instance, Android GingerBread that runs on my HTC Explorer looks like this:

[image: HTC Explorer Look & Feel]

The same Android on the Sony Xperia U looks quite different, as seen here:

[image: Sony Xperia U Look & Feel]

Is there any way I can get the look and feel of Sony's version of Android on my HTC? Any skin pack/transformation pack/hack/firmware replacement that might enable this?

(In a general sense, how can I customize the look and feel of my Android device to look more like that of another manufacturer?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the home screens, you need to install a new Launcher application - search the Play Store for `Launcher` and see what is available.

Comment: Being new to Android, I didn't know that the transformation packs were referred to as "Launchers". Based on your pointer, I found [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.xperia&hl=en), the Xperia inspired theme for GO Launcher EX, as well as standalone Xperia S Launchers [here](http://www.iapktop.com/tag/xperia-s-home-launcher-apk). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the appareance of your device using the GO Launcher EX applicationn that's available in the Play store.

If you are looking for the intergration of (new/old) features on your device your best bet might be installing a different ROM. A ROM is like a modified version of Android. It requires your device to be rooted though. 
There aren't many ROM databases on the net but [the unlocker](http://theunlockr.com/downloads/android-downloads/android-roms/) provides you the tool to select a ROM based on your device manufacturer.

Comment: There are many `Home Launchers` in Play Store. Go Launcher is the crapiest one...

Comment: @Kiwi1 - Thanks! GO Launcher EX was exactly the kind of app I was looking for, that can transform the way my OS looks. Plus, I found the [Xperia theme for it](http://www.iapktop.com/tag/xperia-s-home-launcher-apk)!